# Python adding day number with average

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My code so far is;

```
days = int(input("How many days: "))
values = []

for i in range(days):
    x = 0
    print("It's the " +str(x+1) +" day")
    values.append(int(input("Give the working hours ")))
```

I pretty much want it to raise the day after every question and store the given 'working hours' to use for later. I can't seem to get it work anyhow. This is how I want to program to run;

```
How many days: 2
It's the 1. day.
Give the working hours: 7.5 
It's the 2. day. 
Give the working hours: 8.5 
Hours all together: 16.00
Average day lenght: 8
Given hours: 7.5 8.5
```

I know to sum the working hours and calculate the average, but can't do the rest. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem specifically?

Comment: To add day number automatically within the input, so if my input is 3 days, it prints "It's the 1. day" until "It's the 3. day"
Also to store the given working hours so I can use them again in the end (and calculate the average)

Comment: Well as far as I can see your code do that exactly. Could you add the error message, wrong result ?

Comment: It only prints "Today is the 1 day". So the number doesn't go up like "Today it the 2 day" etc. Even if I give 5 to the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as full code:

```
days = int(input("How many days: "))
values = []

for i in range(days):
    print("It's the",str(i+1)+". day.")
    values.append(float(input("Give the working hours ")))
print('Hours all together: %.2f'%sum(values))
print('Average day length:',int(sum(values)/len(values)))
print('Given hours:',' '.join(map(str,values)))
```

So basically make `x`, `i`.

And also make second input `float`, not `int`.

Then we add the prints.

Example Output:

```
How many days: 2
It's the 1. day.
Give the working hours 7.5
It's the 2. day.
Give the working hours 8.5
Hours all together: 16.00
Average day length: 8
Given hours: 7.5 8.5
```

Comment: Thanks man! Just to clarify for myself, if I'm not mistaken does the %.2f'% in your code restrict it to two decimals (this is what I want, but I know only the round() way).
I'll make sure to study this

Comment: @Daniel Happy to help, :-),, you're correct, it does what you think it does :-)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, but also got a question with this:
.join(map(str,values)) Can you explain a bit what .join and map() does? Thanks :D

Comment: @Daniel Sorry for late reply, `map` basically applies the first argument (function) too all the elements in the second argument (sequence), so convert to list, tuple, etc.., otherwise it's a `map` object, so usually, no function for what you want, so create function with `lambda`.http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html and http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html

Comment: @Daniel OTOH, `join` only needs one argument, which should be a sequence, so the string you do join to will be the separation between the values of the argument (sequence), https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `x` and use the index `i` on the for loop:

```
days = int(input("How many days: "))
values = []

for i in range(days):
    print("Today is the " + str(i + 1) + " day")
    values.append(float(input("Give the working hours ")))
```

The problem is if you set `x = 0` in each iteration of the for loop `str(x + 1)` will always be `'1'`. Also instead of `int` you should use `float` if you are going to pass decimal values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I totally forgot that I have to add the `i` and not make a `x` to add the numbers.